# Getting a number of cells summed in a =SUM formula

Tags: google-sheets

I just summed up a some cells using the =SUM formula.

I have to multiply the number of cells being summed by 6, so my question is:

Is there any way for me to get another cell to display the amount of cells being summed in the =SUM formula?

Comment: Sure, just use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`...

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work, but due to the amount of cells I'm selecting I was wondering if there was a shorter way then having to select all the cells again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in whatever cell you need the value
:

```
=count(A1:A)*6
```